# What is the meaning of "<-" operator in bash?

Tags: bash

In [the installation instructions for KnockPY](https://github.com/guelfoweb/knock#user-content-install) it says:

```
nano knockpy/config.json <- set your virustotal API_KEY
```

I need to understand what exact is '<-' doing in this command.

Comment: Are you sure that isn’t a comment?  Where did you get that command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Comment: It seems rather wrong to point to a purported duplicate answer that _is not the answer here_, and to reject a question where a questioner is _quite rightly_ ensuring that xe knows what the magic installation instructions that xe is supposed to copy and paste _actually do_.

Comment: @Scott, obviously it is not duplicate

Answer (score 4):

This text [was written by Gianni Amato](https://github.com/guelfoweb/knock/commit/ce6f4b1a78b6af6eaa6f2ed8ae21084b7a2a50f2#diff-88b99bb28683bd5b7e3a204826ead112R51).  It is a comment saying what you should do when you open this file in an editor (i.e. you should configure `API_KEY` in the file).  It should have been written:

```
nano knockpy/config.json # set your virustotal API_KEY
```

You might care to submit a bug report to the author so that other people are not confused by this in the future.